# Webscraping: Loop through multiple urls

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I have successfully scrapped several websites individually.
However, now I want to have a single script so that I don't have to run each script individually all the time.
I would like to build a for loop that goes through all websites and replaces the x with a string.
Unfortunately, there are no numbers, with which I could go through the individual pages with "for x in range", but there are just the strings mentioned.

Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
    

movielist = []

for x in ... ('action', 'comedy', 'thriller', 'drama', 'sport'): # what should i insert instead of ...?
    r = requests.get(f'https://movie.com/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    spiele = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'row'})
```

The site is not real, its just a question how to do that.

I am very happy about your help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the ...
Your tuple is iterable to you can go through every element like this:

```
for x in ('action', 'comedy', 'thriller', 'drama', 'sport'): # what should i insert instead of ...?
    print(f'https://movie.com/{x}')
```

output:

```
https://movie.com/action
https://movie.com/comedy
https://movie.com/thriller
https://movie.com/drama
https://movie.com/sport
```

Comment: I was close :D
But that makes sense.
You saved my night thank you so much :)

Comment: Sure you was the first one who solved it :)

Comment: i have another question but dont wanna open a new Thread for it. I just wanna delete the rows where a column = 'stringxyz' and in it there is the word 'empty'. I was doing it that way: newdf[newdf.stringxyz != 'EMPTY']
But it was just working the first time and now nothing is happening -.-

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you have and your desired output?

Comment: The complete row should be deleted in the csv file if the word 'EMPTY' is in the column 'stringxyz'. At the moment it still stays there. I got already this mentioned line of code:
newdf[newdf.stringxyz != 'EMPTY']

Comment: i think i got it:
newdf.drop(index=newdf[newdf['stringxyz'] == 'EMPTY'].index, inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close! Just iterate through movie list tuple and x will be next element for each iteration.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

movielist = ('action', 'comedy', 'thriller', 'drama', 'sport')

for x in movielist:
    print(f'https://movie.com/{x}')
    r = requests.get(f'https://movie.com/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    spiele = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'row'})
```

With this slight change it will make requests, use BS and print to constructed urls to console:

```
https://movie.com/action
https://movie.com/comedy
https://movie.com/thriller
https://movie.com/drama
https://movie.com/sport
```

However, you probably should store result after each iteration somewhere, for example append "spiele" to some list or just use it somehow.